# Seeming inconsistency between Object#method and Object#methods

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I think my question is best captured by this irb session:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'sinatra'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> method(:get)
=> #<Method: Object(Sinatra::Delegator)#get>
irb(main):003:0> methods.include?(:get)
=> false
irb(main):004:0> wtf?
NoMethodError: undefined method `wtf?' for main:Object
        from (irb):4
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0>
```

My question, which is really a ruby and not a sinatra-specific question, is how can `method(:get)` be returning something while `methods` is not including `:get` in its returned array?

Comment: What ruby version are you working on?

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. This took a bit of head scratching but in the end the answer is found in the [documentation of `methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-methods), which says:

> Returns a list of the names of **public and protected** methods of obj. This will include all the methods accessible in obj’s ancestors.

And then you combine it with the Sinatra source:

```
module Delegator
  def self.delegate(*methods)
    methods.each do |method_name|
      define_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
        ...
      end
      private method_name    # <- here
    end
  end

  delegate :get, :patch, :put, :post, :delete, :head, :options, ... 
end
```

And we can see what the problem was. Then the solution becomes:

```
private_methods.include?(:get)
=> true
```

Comment: @Jonah To me it seems the idea is these methods are never meant to be called from anywhere else but directly from inside the Sinatra App class or on global scope. You never want to (or should?) call them with an explicit receiver, like `someobj.get`. They are simply there to be used as syntactic sugar metaprogramming constructs. Not as actual instance methods. That's what `private` does; it prevents you for calling a method with an explicit receiver. So those methods essentially become like Ruby "keywords" when used in this way.